# Google Reader format is broken on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

On my home computer, my Google Reader format is unviewable with Chrome. I can view it fine on my work computer using Chrome though.

This is what it looks like (click to enlarge).

[image]

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Are both versions of Chrome the same? Have you done the usual, e.g. cleared Cache and Cookies?

Comment: What happens when you change from list view to expanded and back again?

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed? Have you tried opening GReader in Incognito mode?

Comment: Works in incognito mode. Guess it could be an extension, though when I didn't have any extensions it didn't work either.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue myself

I use AVAST as my virus checker. When installed it had the Web Reputation Plugin for chrome activated. De-activiateing fixed the problem.

My advice - go through your Chrome extensions one by one until you fin the culprit

Comment: Haven't checked this message in a long time. Come to find out, it was the Avast extension. I didn't realize that AVast had added a plugin to chrome.

Comment: This is awesome, had the exact same problem. Thank goodness for StackExchange :D